# What's the easiest to remember publicly pingable IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, ping

For frequent network troubleshooting purposes, do you know a publicly pingable host with an easy to remember IP address (such as 1.2.3.4)?

Comment: I initially misread your question - I seemed that you are searching for an IP address that can be used publicly (globally? system independant). I guess the question could be re-written as 'What's the easiest to remember pingable _public_ IP address?'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping -a 4.2.2.2

Pinging vnsc-bak.sys.gtei.net [4.2.2.2] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=246
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=246
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=246
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=246

Ping statistics for 4.2.2.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 14ms, Average = 11ms
```

Comment: This is a good example, because its run by a fundamental internet backbone. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_3_Communications

Comment: @Kent - that is correct. It is always there, and it is a DNS server as well.

Answer (score 27):

8.8.8.8 is Google's new public dns server which is easy to remember and quite likely to be up ;-)

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=242 time=18.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=242 time=18.0 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.024/18.366/18.599/0.292 ms

$ host 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
4.2.2.2
4.2.2.6

208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

add these in /etc/hosts for easy pinging :)

Comment: +1 for OpenDNS's servers, those seem to be ingrained in my head..

Answer (score 1):

Take any host and use [hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) !

ip1:: 122.123.232.98

After that , when I type ip1 it wll replace it with 122.123.232.98
That way you can take any host and don't need to remember anything.

Answer (score 1):

I use 4.2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

If you need an HTTP response, `190.9.9.190` works

Comment: Yip, `14.4.4.4` no longer works. `190.9.9.190` works (for now...)

Comment: Try 79.170.44.91 instead, it will be online 24/7 under SLA

Answer (score 1):

Using a script i get the following list
of IP's - which are easy to remember - and
have a webserver running on port 80:

this is the list (2018-jan-23)

```
http://23.23.23.23
http://41.41.41.41
http://80.80.80.80
http://127.127.127.127
```

but all these hosts dont seem the work reliable...
the idea was to give endusers an easy check, if DNS is faulty.

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
L=

for I in $(seq 1 254); do
  IP=$I.$I.$I.$I
  nc -z -v -w3 $IP 80 && wget -O - http://$IP && L="$L $IP"
  I=$(( I + 1 ))
done

echo $L
```

Answer (score 1):

A new one with http response: 1.1.1.1 (http 302)

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 works every time and is very easy to remember.

Actually, I would recommend using hostnames:
c:[windows directory]\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: He needs something on the public internet.  He's not testing the loopback interface.

Comment: engage humour detector